# At runtime can I determine an animation's frame rate?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

My goal is to identify when an animation is running on lower-end hardware (lower-end GPU) and change the animation or storyboard to deliver a better user experience (or less animation).

Is it possible to determine an animation's frame rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there is no way to get access to the frame rate. You could detect the amount of time between each report of the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event, but that event only tracks when the animation system has finished sending its updates to the rendering subsystem (which very well may decide to skip frames depending on the state of the graphics card).

There's a very interesting discussion on tracking WPF framerate on the MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/95300fe6-8958-4b9b-ad37-581a9bdefccf). Pretty much all of that should be applicable to Windows Store XAML apps.

If all you're wanting to do is swap out animations if they're taking too long to run, [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) may be suitable for what you need.